# App freezes after opening it from an alertView received from a push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have embedded APNS to my app and I navigate to a screen where I have details of the notification. The problem is, when clicked on the view button in the alert view, the app navigates to the .xib file and freezes.
What can I do to workaround this?
Heres the code used to open the viewController xib:

```
RearTableViewController *rearView = [[RearTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RearTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Details" bundle:nil];
    detailsViewController.messageID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"messageId"] intValue];
    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailsViewController];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearView];

SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

mainRevealController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = mainRevealController;
```

Comment: Application can get APNS message not only in applicationDidFinishLaunching..., if application is launched, then it will get APNS in ..didReceiveRemoteNotification:.. I don't think that changing of rootViewController in this case is good idea.

Comment: I have tried presenting a view controller too.. That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This may Help you.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    SplashVC *rootVC = [[SplashVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
    [navigation setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is my code when i receive push and show alert. If alerts one of the button pressed then this will present my view controller.

```
LocationViewController *locationVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocationVC"];
                                  locationVC.latitude = fLat;
                                  locationVC.longitude = fLong;
                                  [self.navController presentViewController:locationVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have tried this too. The application still freezes and this only happens when navigated to from an alertView.

Comment: when alert is shown? when push is received at that time alert is shown?

Comment: No,bro. It still doesn't work. The application crashes now

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: `SettingsVC *controller = [[SettingsVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`   do you have just tried this simple. because i'm using this in one of my old project\